# vb.net How can I execute a task between certain hours only

Tags: vb.net

I have a private sub `Count_Average` that does stuff and I have a timer `TimerAverage` that is going to execute  `Count_Average`. Right now its executing each minute, 24/7 - but I want it to only execute between certain hours only. Which would be between 07:00 - 23:59:59. How can I set that "propertie"?

Below is what my TimerAverage.tick does at the moment and also what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
Private Sub TimerAverage_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TimerAverage.Tick

Dim dateValue As DateTime = DateTime.Now
Dim startTime As DateTime = dateValue.Date + New TimeSpan(07, 0, 0)
Dim endTime As DateTime = dateValue.Date + New TimeSpan(23, 59, 0)

''''' Below is a demonstration of what I want (which obviously don't work)

''''' If not datetime.now is between starttime 
'     Do nothing

'else

  TimerAverage.Stop()
  Count_Average()
  TimerAverage.Start()

'end if
```

I know this is a bad attempt, its more like a demonstration of what I'm trying to accomplish. I've tried to figure out how to write this correctly, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the range is `7:00` - `23:59` you could simply use:

```
If DateTime.Now.Hour >= 7 Then
    'do something
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, Tezzo! I assume this will work perfectly. :) Guess I was , because this was simpler than I thought it would be.